# Adding new site language via PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp, alternate-language

i am trying to add new site languages via PowerShell with this code:

$Context = Get-PnPContext
$Web = $Context.Web
$Context.Load($Web)
Invoke-PnPQuery

$Web.IsMultilingual = $true
$Web.AddSupportedUILanguage(1031)
$Web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery

But it is not working for the new experience and translation feature. It just show me default page for the language settings, but nothing has changed:

[image]

Is there a way to set it via PowerShell?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Please use the script here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161599/add-alternative-language-to-sharepoint-online-sites-powershell

I tested it and works fine.

And the LCID list is here: http://dupdupduptop.blogspot.com/2012/11/sharepoint-locale-id-lcid-table.html

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. The script executes without an error, but the language is not added to the site.

Comment: @Johannes Did you change the LCID?

Comment: yes, i tried multiple lcids. Just to clarify the result i want to achieve is a added site language for translation: [link] https://imgur.com/a/sWRmpbS

Comment: @Johannes, just like Martin said, you can check it by navigating to site settings>language settings>Show advanced settings, you can find the new language has been checked. Which means if the user has add the language as preferred language, he will see the translated site page when he access the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on "Show advanced settings" my guess is you will see that the language has been added.

$Web.IsMultilingual doesn't do anything, it is a relic from several versions of SharePoint ago when not all templates could support multiple languages.  Now they all do.